# Клиент Telegram для парсинга сообщений

Tags: python, python-3.x, telethon

Я хотел бы узнать вот какую вещь... Мне понадобилось написать парсер сообщений из телеги в вк. Я решил запилить это сперва в виде бота, но потом узнал, что телеграм не предоставляет возможности подключения бота к каналу ( а точнее, только админ может добавить бота в канал ). Тогда мой взгляд пал на библиотеку telethon, позволяющая работать непосредственно с клиентом API Telegram. Так вот, казалось бы я ответил на все вопросы, которые меня интересовали, но есть большое НО.

Как мне обойти проверку авторизации клиента в классе TelegramClient, который принимает api_id и api_hash? Точнее, либа просит ввести меня номер телефона и ввести подтверждающий код, но что мне делать когда я запущу "бота" на сервере? Либо же как-то возможно с эмитировать ввод данных?

Comment: Это нарушение правил использования telegram, соответственно противозаконно

Comment: @Inventor Тогда зачем используют библиотеку telethon?) Если всё время при перезапуске на машине нужно будет вводить данные))

Comment: это функционал для того, чтобы ты мог создать свой клиент телеграма и пользоваться им. А не для того чтобы создавать ботов, которые прикрываются обычными пользователями. Первое это не запрещено, а второе - нарушение

Comment: И что получается, я никаким образом не смогу автоматизировать парсинг сообщений из телеги в вк?(

Comment: Если админ паблика разрешит то можешь, а иначе это кража контента и нарушение авторских прав

Comment: Так какая же это кража, когда я собираюсь из технического канала вуза пересылать информацию в общий поток технических групп вуза

Comment: Ну попроси у админа разрешение добавить бота и парси, если админ разрешит

Comment: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605436/how-i-can-restore-sessions-old-in-telethon-telegram-and-connect-this-againwitho) Неправильно ли я понимаю, что я могу подключиться по файлу сессии при этом не получая код от телеграм?